# How to programmatically set custom display settings for an RSS feed?

Tags: views, feeds, entities

I am using Drupal 7 and Views 3.0-RC1.

I have defined an RSS feed for a view, but the full node content keeps showing up instead of the teaser. I believe it is because of these two issues:

- http://drupal.org/node/1211008
- http://drupal.org/node/1137116

The steps that appear to work are to:

- Enable a custom display for RSS,
- Configure the RSS custom display truncate the teaser and hide extra fields,
- Enable the view to display full text for RSS.

I need to make this work programmatically as part of a features module.

The first step is easy. I do it with the following code in my .module file:

```
    function mymodule_entity_info_alter(&$entity_info) {
      $entity_info['customtype']['view modes']['rss'] = array (
        'label' => t('RSS Feed'),
        'custom settings' => TRUE,
      );
```

The last step is easy, as I can export the view.

The middle step has me stumped. I can't figure out how to set the display properties on the RSS display. I suspect it has something to do with field settings, but I can't seem to pull the pieces together. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

@JeremyFrench pointed out that the Features Module correctly exports the field settings for the view-mode, which fulfilled the middle step. No extra API calls is necessary.

My problem was with step 1. Though field settings are defined per-content-type and per-view-mode, the actual definition of view modes is independent of content-types. All content types share the same set of view modes, though each can implement their own field settings for that view mode.

This means that in my call to `hook_entity_info_alter()`, I should not have referenced customtype, I should just reference 'node'. That simple change enables everything to work.